# How to interpolate with MATLAB 3D usind scatteredinterpolant plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have to make a topography plot using x (latitude), y (longitude) and z (altitude) of an area. I want to plot a 3D plot and have done the following:

```
m=load('try.mat'); %matrix containing 3 columns have 40000 data each
x=reshape(m(:,1),400,400); %latitudes
y=reshape(m(:,2),400,400); %longitudes
z=reshape(m(:,3),400,400); %altitude
surf(x,y,z); % for surface plot
```

I have done the above plot however I get are not so continuous plot and I need some interpolation in between the points which are not very close enough. So kindly help me with the interpolation part.

I am adding an image:

[image]

Comment: maybe you can provide something more, to have a minimum working example (MWE)

Comment: See [MATLAB's documentation for interpolation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation-1.html)

Comment: I am not able to understand the documentation that's why I have asked for help and if anyone good with matlab be able to help it will be very good.

Comment: @Alessandro Cuttin I haev added a image . It is the output file that i am getting however i want a continuous surface

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with the shape and distribution of your data. Please check the example of "Displaying Nonuniform Data on a Surface" in the [Representing Data as a Surface documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html) and report back

Comment: The -6 is probably for "URGENT please". Don't get into the habit of spoiling your questions with that please - if only because too many downvotes will lock your account from asking new questions.

Comment: @NoelSegura I have scatteredinterpolant which generated a matrix like this.
f = 

  scatteredInterpolant with properties:

                 Points: [40000x2 double]
                 Values: [40000x1 double]
                 Method: 'linear'
    ExtrapolationMethod: 'linear'

Now how to use this matrix in matlab

Comment: @KuntalChaudhuri scatteredinterpolant would create a function, not a matrix. Then you can use that function to create a surface. You can start by checking the ezsurf command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`surf` is a function which displays a quad-mesh, from your output I can only tell that you did not input the data in the right order or shape, it seems to randomly connect the wrong points.

In the simplest case (a regular quad-mesh) means that each column of X contains the same value and each row of Y. A small example:

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(0:4);
>> X

X =

     0     1     2     3     4
     0     1     2     3     4
     0     1     2     3     4
     0     1     2     3     4
     0     1     2     3     4

>> Y

Y =

     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
```

Check if this is possible for your data.

Comment: I have the x, y and z values from 1-40000 which I had converted to a square matrix of 200x200 (3 in number). Now how do I use the above example that you told to help my data?
Kindly tell me how to use put this in the surf command as it would take not more than 4 inputs (x,y,z,c)